# Lost records in datasnap REST client

Tags: delphi, datasnap, delphi-xe7, firedac

I have a DataSnap/REST server and client application.

The server have a method to return one or more datasets with some number of records but, when this number of records is greater than 50, the first 50 records aren't received by the client application.

I have debugged the server application and the SQL statement is correct (I have executed it from IBExpert and returns the correct number of records).

I have used XE7, FireDAC and Firebird.

Into the server application I have this method to return a dataset

```
procedure TSvrMethodsMdl.AddTable(SQL, TabName: string; JSON: TFDJSONDataSets);
var
  Q: TFDQuery;
begin
  Q := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    Q.Connection := conTPV;
    Q.Transaction := conTPV.Transaction;
    Q.SQL.Text := SQL;
    TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(JSON, TabName, Q);
  finally
    //    FreeAndNil(Q);
  end;
end;
```

Into the client application, for receiving records, I have this code

```
var
  LDataSetList: TFDJSONDataSets;
  LDataSet: TFDDataSet;
  tTemp: TFDMemTable;
begin
....
  // get remote data
  LDataSetList := CliConnectMdl.SvrMethodsMdlClient.GetDataChanged(Shop, ResError);
  // process data
  LDataSet := TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValueByName(LDataSetList, MyTabName);
  tTemp.AppendData(LDataSet);
```

I think that is some of configuration, but I cant find what.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting `Q.FetchOptions.Mode := fmAll;` ?

Comment: yes, with the same result.